# While loop is not working to read file in perl script

Tags: perl, scripting, while-loop

I am writing a perl script and I am trying to read two diff files..

## first file

```
open my $data1, "<", "/tmp/CSI_to_PROD_111111_20141004_225038/att_application.properties"
    or die "Unable to open prod file";

while (<$data1>) {
    chomp();
    foreach $line (<$data1>) {
        next if ( $line =~ /(^\s*#|^$)/ );
        chomp($line);
        foreach $token (@csitokens) {
            if ( $line =~ /$token=/ ) {
                my ( $tok, @val ) = split( /=/, $line, 2 );
                print "@val\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
close($data1) or warn "Not able to close fil: \n";
```

## second file

```
open my $data2, "<", "/opt/app/d1ebl1m5/dv02/cingbt02/J2EEServer/config/AMSS/application/properties/att_application.properties_try"
    or die "unable to open file: $!";

while (<$data2>) {
    foreach $line1 (<$data2>) {
        print "$line1";
    }
}
close($data2) or warn "Not able to close fil: \n";
```

The loop for first file is working fine and displaying the output but the second loop doesnt display anything..

Comment: while reads a line at time from the file. Foreach does the same. So you're jumping the tracks.

Answer (score 3):

There are too many `while` and `foreach` loops. You need only one of them:

```
open my $data2, "<" , "/opt/app/d1ebl1m5/dv02/cingbt02/J2EEServer/config/AMSS/application/properties/att_application.properties_try"  
   or die "unable to open file: $!";

while( my $line1 = <$data2> ) {
    print "$line1";
} 
close($data2);
```

The same is applicable for the first loop. Yo have also an error on your *die-check* after the file open